# Activity getting destroyed when starting another activity for file viewing

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm performing file viewing operation as follows:

```
private void openFile(File file, String format) {
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String mimeType = "*/*";
            if (format.length() > 0) {
                mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(format);
                if (mimeType == null)
                    mimeType = "*/*";
            } else
                mimeType = "*/*";
            intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeType);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginSuccessActivity.this,
                        constants.Error_NoCompatibleApp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginSuccessActivity.this,
                    constants.Error_DocNotFound, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is working fine, as I get app chooser pop-up for the filetypes which has multiple apps related to it(for eg. kingsoft office and polaris office for word file) OR directly file is opened for the filetypes which has only one app related to it(HTMLViewer for html file).

What I don't understand is my main activity is getting destroyed in few moments after calling file viewer activity. I've checked this by placing logs in `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`. So, after file viewing is done, when I press back key, instead of taking back to app, it navigated to main menu.

I tried with `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` instead of `startActivity(intent);` hoping that it'll preserve my main activity as it'll be waiting for result, but to no avail.

Please note that I've added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest file and

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

in java file.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Sometimes, mind you, "Sometimes", I get follwing messages on log:

```
 file:// Uri exposed through Intent.getData()
 java.lang.Throwable: file:// Uri exposed through Intent.getData()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1597)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2338)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:7194)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1418)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onIntentSelected(ResolverActivity.java:407)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.startSelected(ResolverActivity.java:299)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onButtonClick(ResolverActivity.java:289)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's very huge. It doesn't work appropriately after particular file is selected for opening and viewing. Before that, all works fine.

Comment: use startActivityForResult rather startActivity.

Comment: as mentioned in question, I have already used that

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your `Intent` and try to Start Activity,

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setType(Your_MimeType);
```

I m using this code in my App

```
String MimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(myFile.getAbsolutePath());

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setType(MimeType);
Uri uri_path = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
intent.setDataAndType(uri_path, MimeType);
try
{
    _context.startActivity(intent);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(_context,"Activity Not Found..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) link also for better understanding

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for replying, but unfortunately, this is not working (:

Comment: as u can see in my question, I've already added this line: `intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeType);`

Comment: i am doing same task as u r and i have added `setType` tag to intent and also `setDataAndType` tag. and it is working perfectly. thats why i m suggesting you to add. @GAMA

Comment: After opening particular file, you'll be navigated away on 3rd party app. When you press back, do you navigate back to your app?

Comment: ohk i don't think so it was not working perfectly same code is working for me @GAMA

Comment: Thank you! You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Activity can get destroyed any time. If someone has some data to retain one can do as follows:

```
class MyActivity {

private String mMyString;

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) {

b.putString("MYDATA", mMyString);
super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
super.onCreate(savedState)
if(savedState != null) {
 mMyString = savedState.getString("MYDATA");
}

}
```

You can this way create your own subclass `private static class State implements Serializable` and save it in `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: Pardon me, but I'm not that well-versed with saving state and all. I guess this should have some simple operation. I don't buy the fact that, as soon as file viewer app(like polaris office) opens, system runs out of memory and hence closes previous activity.

Comment: It surely can. There is even a debugging option for that in Developer Options|Don't Save Activities. There is no way to guarantee the Activity won't be destroyed so you have to save your state.

Comment: I've checked on both emulator and real device, `Don't Save Activities` is not checked. Still it exit the app on both emulator and device.

Comment: Of course it's not checked. Just save your state and you will be fine. You do not have to save the contents of your activity's views it gets saved in the base onSaveInstanceState. You just have to save any extra state you have

Comment: This process of opening file in 3rd party app happens from my 2nd activity(1st is login) and that too from 3rd view within ViewFlipper. Now, when file is opened and my app gets exited, after file viewing, when I click back the app icon, will it directly go on 3rd View of 2nd activity?

Comment: It will go back to that activity which called the third party activity before by means of startActivitty or startActivityForResult. If it so happens that activity got destroyed it will be recreated.

Comment: When I open a file from 2nd activity using a 3rd party app, 2nd activity is getting destroyed and app is getting exited. When I click back from 3rd party app, I come to main menu of device and then I click app icon, it's showing 1st activity and **NOT** the calling(2nd) activity.